# What is the antonym of origin in a cartesian plot?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am looking for a term which means "place at which both variables are highest on a plot. Does such a word exist?

Comment: Such a point might not exist, but it could be called a dominating point (in some situations).

Comment: Maxima, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima ??

Comment: I'm looking for the combined maxima, and the term is necessarily plural.  Dominating point seems closer, but maybe a bit obscure.